# Process flow when using button events in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm only just getting started with C# WPF forms and came across a small issue that I can't find a resolution for.

I have a button that currently just checks to see if a folder exists.

The correct flow is;

1. Write into a textbox to say the process has started.
2. Perform the process.
3. Write into the textbox to say the process has finished (successfully or not)

What's actually happening is that when the button is pressed, all actions are completed and then the textbox is written.

Is there a way to get the textbox to populate as each process finishes - the plan is to perform multiple actions on a single button press eventually and log each one as it happens - the final process may take 30+ minutes hence the requirement to keep the user updated as the process is working?

```
    private void Button_Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            textbox_OutputBox.Text = textbox_OutputBox.Text.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " : " + "Folder check started" + Environment.NewLine);
            
                if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Windows"))
                {
                    textbox_OutputBox.Text = textbox_OutputBox.Text.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " : " + "Folder missing" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    textbox_OutputBox.Text = textbox_OutputBox.Text.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " : " + "folder not missing" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            
        }
```

Hopefully this all makes sense but if not, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Your processing is on the ui thread. That thread is the thing will show the user any chane to text so you block that.  Make the handler async. After each point you update progress use await.Task.Delay(20); to  give it some time to update the ui. Or. Make all your processing run on a background thread and use dispatcher.invokeasync to update ui properties. Google it rather than ask me what I mean by dispatcher.invokeasync.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing takes significant time you probably want to run it on a background thread to avoid blocking the UI. One way to report progress is to take a parameter that the processing method updates, and a timer that updates the UI on the main thread periodically. For example

```
public void MyProcess(ConcurrentQueue<string> processedItems, CancellationToken cancel){
    foreach(var item in items){
        cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // do processing
        processedItems.Add(item.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Add a button that cancels the corresponding [cancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-5.0), and a timer that updates a textbox with all the lines from the processedItems collection every second or so. Use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0) to run the method on a background thread, and keep in mind to await the task inside a try block to catch any exceptions so they can be handled.